# Authentication is failing but can log in using those credentials PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a small issue with postgresql. For some reason my project keeps telling me that my password is incorrect. To address this I did the following :

`ALTER USER userps WITH PASSWORD 'userps';`

`postgres=# GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DB project TO userps ;`

However when I run `python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:5000` I'm getting  `FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "userps"`

Funny enough, if I do `psql -d DB -U userps` I can log into the database with the password defined but `DATABASE_URL=postgres://userps:userps@localhost/DB` is giving me incorrect password.

I saw alot of questions speaking of the pg_hba.conf file but I have edited it (see attached) and no change.

[image]

Comment: Postgres version? Did you reload the server after making the `pg_hba.conf` changes? Do you have more then once instance of Postgres running and are you sure you are connecting to the correct one? Looking at the Postgres log will help. Add answers as update to your question.

Comment: Whatever else may be going on, your GRANT cannot succeed, it has a syntax error

Comment: @AdrianKlaver it's version 12.8, I've restarted multiple times. Where do I check which one I am connecting to?

Comment: @jjanes, actually it will because the second `local` line has an `auth` of `md5` and the user is not `postgres`.

Comment: Look in the Postgres log for the server you think you are connecting to. If you have not already done so it would help to set `log_connections`/`log_disconnections` in `postgresql.conf` per [What to log](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-LOGGING-WHAT).

Comment: @Niana  Instead of restarting it, I would just shut it down and leave it down.  If you can still connect, then you must be connecting to something else. (and if you get the authentication failed error, that too must be connecting to something else)